# Adding dynamic tags to telegraf input

Tags: telegraf

We're using [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) to collect CloudWatch data from AWS and output it to InfluxDB.

We need to add dynamic tags to the input, s.t if `"instancId == 12345"`, add tag `"user = 3"`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [`processors`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors). If you have just a set of known values that you want to work with, I think [`enum`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors/enum) would be the best option. Here is the example updated for your case:

```
[[processors.enum]]
  [[processors.enum.mapping]]
    ## Name of the field to map
    field = "instancId"

    ## Destination field to be used for the mapped value.  By default the source
    ## field is used, overwriting the original value.
    dest = "user"

    ## Default value to be used for all values not contained in the mapping
    ## table.  When unset, the unmodified value for the field will be used if no
    ## match is found.
    default = 0

    ## Table of mappings
    [processors.enum.mapping.value_mappings]
      123 = 1
      1234 = 2
      12345 = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [CONFIGURATION.md](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#input-config-tags) docs:

```
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = false
  totalcpu = true
  [inputs.cpu.tags]
    tag1 = "foo"
    tag2 = "bar"
```

Comment: This doesn't set a tag based on the metric returned. It adds two tags to any CPU metric parsed by the cpu input.